# extend the /home partition ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, partitioning, gparted

I started using Linux (ubuntu os dual boot) lately and the installation completed smoothly. I allocated the `swap` and `root` partition in SSD and the `home` partition in HDD. After that, I realized the `home` partition is too small and tried to add more space to it. But I can't do anything with the `home` partition. It can't be extended from the left and it always says that "the partition is busy".

Here is the HDD structure.

- The first, second and sixth are from Window.
- The fifth is the empty space.
- The last one is the `home` partition.

[image: HDD structure on gparted]

Comment: What if you `resize/move` the `/dev/sda5` partition with **gparted**, and get free space at the **right** of this partition, then merge it with `/dev/sda6` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only resize partitions that are not currently in use. Thus, shut down the machine, boot a live installation CD and use gparted from a live session. gparted is available by default in a live session, not in an installed instance of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

There is no contiguous space to enlarge the sda6 partition into. You must first move the sda5 partition to the left. This will place the free space next to sda6, and then you can enlarge it.

You must do this from a live session and the partitions to be modified cannot be mounted.

*Backup your data before doing this*